# Log in manager doesn't appear after editing /etc/X11/default-display-manager

Tags: gdm, login-screen, kdm

I have ubuntu 11.10 , and I installed kde and I choosed kdm mistakly, as mentioned [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/change-from-kdm-to-gdm-547964/#post2720453) I did this procedure

> Pretty simple. Open the file /etc/X11/default-display-manager with your editor of choice. Make sure you invoke that editor as root, otherwise it won't work. In that file there's a single line: /usr/bin/kdm Change that to /usr/bin/gdm and save the file. Reboot and you're in Gnome.

now ,after booting, the log in manager `gdm or kdm` didn't appear .
how can I fix this?

Comment: Run /usr/bin/gdm or gdm from a console to see if it runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the content of `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` to former content (`/usr/bin/gdm`) and log in manager came up .